# Docker Quickstart Terminal - fork: retry: No child processes

Tags: git, bash, docker, windows-10, docker-toolbox

Installed [Docker Toolbox for Windows](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox) but after running Docker Quickstart Terminal i get the error:
[image: Docker Quickstart Terminal Error]

Machine Information:

- Windows 10 Home x64;
- Docker Toolbox;
- Bash, Git installed;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are multiple points you need to be aware of:

First of all **Docker Toolbox** is [**Legacy desktop solution**](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/). Docker Toolbox is for older Mac and Windows systems that do not meet the requirements of **Docker for Mac** and **Docker for Windows**. We recommend updating to the newer applications, if possible.

Secondly, if you are installing **Docker for Windows**, you are using it on Windows 10 Home (not Pro), therefore you will not be able to use Hyper-V. So you will have only the option of using Virtual Box. Check [this forum entry](https://forums.docker.com/t/installing-docker-on-windows-10-home/11722).

And another important point is that Virtual Box might function incorrectly on Windows 10. Maybe this was solved in the meantime. Check this [forum entry](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=68590).

Comment: Note: I did not downvote that answer. I thought about Hyper-V: you cannot indeed have both Virtual Box and Hyper-V active at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you don't have [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) installed (or [you would see a similar error](https://superuser.com/a/305108/141))

Second, [as in this thread](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/34992371-launching-git-bash-gives-bash-fork-retry-error) (for Windows 7, but could apply to Windows 10 too), check if you have other software like [BeyondTrust PowerBroker](https://www.beyondtrust.com/blog/powerbroker-for-windows-v7-0-windows-10-support-better-policy-management-and-quarantine/), which could explain why those dll are preempted and not loaded.